# Rails undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yahoo

I am trying to do login using yahoo and trying to fetch token but unable to do so.I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/amirmanji/omniauth-yahoo-oauth2)

Getting error in this line "**access_token = auth_info[:credentials][:token]**"
**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

[omniauth.rb]

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :yahoo_oauth2, 'yahooclientid', 'yahoosecret',
    name: 'yahoo'
end
```

[homecontroller]

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    auth_info = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    access_token = auth_info[:credentials][:token]
    refresh_token = auth_info[:credentials][:refresh_token]
    expires_at = auth_info[:credentials][:expires_at]
  end
```

when i run gem list some gem related to omniauth installted are..

```
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (1.0.0, 0.8.1)
omniauth (1.3.1)
omniauth-facebook (3.0.0, 1.4.1)
omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0, 1.1.1)
omniauth-twitter (1.2.1)
omniauth-yahoo-oauth2 (1.1.0)
```

Comment: What you are getting in `auth_info`?

Comment: i just checked it ,it is giving me nothing

Comment: check your request.env, I bet it does not have omniauth.auth key in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use instance variables or wrap all of it into model method. Here you can see different oauth integrations (linkedin,twitter,gcal). I don't know your usecase but I'm saving the data to the db for different reasons. Linkedin/twitter data needed to display profile attributes, and gcal tokens are important for refreshing access upon new request.

socials controller

```
def create
  raise :test
  begin
    @profile = current_user.profile
    @social = @profile.socials.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    if auth_hash.provider == "google_oauth2"
      flash[:success] = "Your faskyn calendar is now connected to your google calendar!"
    else  
      flash[:success] = "#{@social.provider.camelize} account was successfully updated!"
    end
  rescue
    flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you!"
  end
  redirect_to edit_user_profile_path(current_user)
end

private

def auth_hash
  request.env['omniauth.auth']
end
```

social.rb

```
def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
  calendar not to update the profile
  social_acc = where(provider: auth_hash.provider).first_or_create
  if auth_hash.provider == "google_oauth2"
  social_acc.update(
    uid: auth_hash.uid,
    email: auth_hash.info.email,
    token: auth_hash.credentials.token,
    refresh_token: auth_hash.credentials.refresh_token,
    expires_at: Time.at(auth_hash.credentials.expires_at).to_datetime)
  social_acc
else
  social_acc.update(
    #no first_name, last_name and phone for twitter
    uid: auth_hash.uid,
    token: auth_hash.credentials.token,
    secret: auth_hash.credentials.secret,
    picture_url: auth_hash.info.image,
    location: auth_hash.info.location,
    description: auth_hash.info.description,
    first_name: auth_hash.info.first_name || nil,
    last_name: auth_hash.info.last_name || nil,
    phone: auth_hash.info.phone || nil,
    page_url:   case social_acc.provider
                when 'twitter' then auth_hash.info.urls.Twitter
                when 'linkedin' then auth_hash.info.urls.public_profile
                end
    )
  social_acc
end
```

Comment: I need for yahoo ..I have done authentication using google ...Basically I am getting nothing in my auth_info variable .Even now i am using instance variable over there

Comment: Add:    raise :test    to your index action and check out in the console what auth_hash shows. Or have you already checked the response?

Comment: Actually I am not able to understand what you are trying to say I have not done testing in rails can you tell me what to do on console

Comment: This video at 8:30  https://gorails.com/episodes/omniauth-twitter-sign-in?autoplay=1 You should see the auth_hash attributes. If you call a non-existing one then you will get nil. So let's say you typed auth_info[:credentials][:token], but it should be auth_info[:credentials][:access_token], so you get nil.